# get ROS 2 nodehandle in case of composed nodes

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

Suppose I am using a Composed node as mentioned in this example(https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/composition/src/talker_component.cpp). Now I need to pass a `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr` of this composed Node to another class. In case of ROS 1 nodeletes, this can be done using `getNodeHandle()`. Is there any similar way of doing this in ROS 2 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295701/get-ros-2-nodehandle-in-case-of-composed-nodes/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what you need it for, you might be looking for [get_node_base_interface()](http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#a37e5b136ef0a29853e01d5cecb8e4690) and/or one of the other interfaces an rclcpp Node has: there's more context around them [in this PR](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/277#issuecomment-264062088).

We don't use that function in many of our ROS 2 demos but [this is one example](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/bfd63e19dbcecd77febd8f1dea573a6d3e047d94/lifecycle/src/lifecycle_talker.cpp#L265) (others are in rclcpp's testing code).

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on 2018-09-17**:
get_node_base_interface() is fine for node spinning, but what if I want to use the get_parameter() functionality of the rclcpp::Node class ?

My intention is that I create a composable ros2 Node class  and I want to pass the shared_ptr of that Node class as an argument to another object inside it.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-09-17**:
You can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this since the Node class inherits from it already. But you can also get each interface you want and pass those (more flexible), e.g. `get_node_parameter_interface()`.